# How to boot the GUI so that one single application is launched as part of it?

Tags: applications, custom-roms

I would like to reuse an older Android phone as a digital controller for some applications. It would basically be a browser (or webkit) running full screen (which would display some buttons via javascript which in turn would interact with a backend API).

I have a similar (non-touch, display only) solution on Linux where I start at the end of the boot process `xinit /path/to/xinit/config`, where `/path/to/xinit/config` opens the browser full screen. Before `xinit` there is no concept of GUI, `xinit` starts the graphics core and then runs one single application (the browser). `/path/to/xinit/config`, before launching the browser at the end, does some logistical (non-GUI) tasks.

**Is this a scenario which is replicable on Android?** I would like to ensure that the only graphical element running is the browser (including the notification area, launcher, ...).

In other words: is it possible to boot Android into a "headless" (console) mode, and then start the GUI core with just one application?

Note: this is different from a classical ["kiosk mode"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kiosk%20mode) where one tries to lock out users from accessing other elements of the GUI via an app. I do not have any security/usability considerations as this simple display will run in a safe environment.

EDIT: as pointed out by @Firelord, there were other [similar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116123/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-android-phone-only-run-one-app-and-nothing-else) [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132380/run-a-particular-app-on-boot) but I feel they deal more with a classical kiosk mode than with the separation of the console vs GUI mode.